Expand disagrees with original expression
I have a rather nasty double summation that I am doing. To check that whatever I do it is valid, I routinely substitute in numerical values. I also have checked the result of the double sum by doing a double For loop.
In my double sum, I have many terms that are multiplied by a $s^n\to0$ when $n$ gets very large. As such, my strategy is to expand my result, turn it into a List, find instances of $n$ in the exponent of $s$, and then only continue on this reduced list. Here is an extract of the unaltered expression:
(2^(-3 - 2 n) b s^(-(3/2) - n/2) z^(-2 - n) Conjugate[z]^(-2 - n)
    Sin[x] (-2^(18 + 2 n) B s^(2 + n/2) z^(3 + n) Conjugate[z]^(
      2 + n) + 
     2^(15 + 2 n) B P s^(2 + n/2) z^(3 + n) Conjugate[z]^(2 + n) + 
     2^(2 n) G n P s^(9 + n/2) z^(9 + n) Conjugate[z]^(10 + n)
       Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + n, n, 4/(s z Conjugate[z])] + 
     OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[3047]))/(B^2 (-2 + Sqrt[s] z)^4 (2 + 
     Sqrt[s] z)^2 (-2 + Sqrt[s] Conjugate[z])^4 (2 + 
     Sqrt[s] Conjugate[z])^2 (-4 + s z Conjugate[z])^2)

My original goal was to ensure that every term inside the main brackets was multiplied by $s^{-\frac{3}{2} - \frac{n}{2}}$ in order to then do the exponent checks.
Calling Denominator[] yields 2^(3 + 2 n) B^2 s^(3/2 + n/2) z^(2 + n) (-2 + Sqrt[s] z)^4 (2 + Sqrt[s] z)^2 Conjugate[z]^(2 + n) (-2 + Sqrt[s] Conjugate[z])^4 (2 + Sqrt[s] Conjugate[z])^2 (-4 + s z Conjugate[z])^2. Seeing as I care about quantities with $n$ in the exponent, I define denom=... to be all the terms except those with $n$ in the exponent.
Calling
(2^(-3 - 2 N) s^(-(3/2) - N/2) z^(-2 - N) Conjugate[z]^(-2 - N) *
  Total[List @@ Expand[Numerator[%1]]]/(denom))/.{...}

matches the initial numerical values given before, but if I first set c= List @@ (Expand[2^(-3 - 2 n) * s^(-(3/2) - n/2)* z^(-2 - n)*Conjugate[z]^(-2 - n)*Numerator[%1]]) and then do (Total[c]/(denom))/.{...} then the numerical value disagrees (far more than just a bit of numerical tolerance; opposite sign for one thing).
I thought it might just be catastrophic rounding, or maybe somehow even that the sum had not converged sufficiently, such that I can ignore it and carry on. Yet when I go through the motions of removing $s^n$, which I have successfully done for other regimes / systems, my final result does not reduce down to some known simpler systems when I set the main perturbation parameter to zero. This tells me that something is either going wrong in the search for the exponent or in the expansion of my expression.
I'm using Mathematica 13, in case this is a known bug. Still, any thoughts on what to test, or consider etc would be most welcome!
EDIT: For the code I used to remove the cases with $n$ in the exponent, I negated its operation so as to extract out $n$. I then checked the behaviour of that resulting expression, and sure enough it decays to zero. So what remains really must be what is contributing to the final value?

I eventually found the issue with the help of my friend, and it boils down to this:
temp=Numerator[%] 
F[temp/Denominator[%]]
was NOT the same as 
F[Numerator[%] /Denominator[%]]

So whenever I wanted to something like Simplify[temp], it would lead to the wrong end results. In my particular problem, it had one too many Sin[x]s, and so I had to divide my final result by Sin[x]. That literally solved it ...

Did you really use percents literally as above? If so, that first case should have had %% in the second line. Also I’d recommend not using percent signs at all in anything other than simple examples.

@DanielLichtblau the % here refers to '%5' or something like that. My experience is using percentage signs is fine for doing some immediate calculations in a hurry, but to expect pain upon returning to the notebook. Are you saying that I should avoid them even further?

Your experience is on target. I was only concerned that the posted code was meant to be taken literally.

I am not quite sure of having correctly understood your intentions. Let us see. Here is your initial expression. I expand it:
expr1 = (2^(-3 - 2  n)  b  s^(-(3/2) - n/2)  z^(-2 - n)  Conjugate[
       z]^(-2 - n)  Sin[
      x]  (-2^(18 + 2  n)  B  s^(2 + n/2)  z^(3 + n)  Conjugate[
          z]^(2 + n) + 
       2^(15 + 2  n)  B  P  s^(2 + n/2)  z^(3 + n)  Conjugate[
          z]^(2 + n) + 
       2^(2  n)  G  n  P  s^(9 + n/2)  z^(9 + n)  Conjugate[
          z]^(10 + n)  Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + n, n, 
         4/(s  z  Conjugate[z])] + 
       OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[3047]))/(B^2  (-2 + 
        Sqrt[s]  z)^4  (2 + Sqrt[s]  z)^2  (-2 + 
        Sqrt[s]  Conjugate[z])^4  (2 + Sqrt[s]  Conjugate[z])^2  (-4 +
         s  z  Conjugate[z])^2) // Expand;

As the next step, let us remove s^n:
 expr2 = expr1 /. s^(a_.*n + b_) -> 0 // FullSimplify
    
    (*  (b Sqrt[s] z (32768 B (-8 + P) + 
       G n P s^7 z^6 Conjugate[z]^8 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + n, n, 4/(
         s Abs[z]^2)]) Sin[x])/(8 B^2 (2 + Sqrt[s] z)^2 (2 + Sqrt[s] Conjugate[z])^2(-4 + s z Conjugate[z])^2 (4 + s z Conjugate[z] - 4 Sqrt[s] Re[z])^4)  *)

This is already some result. However, I have the impression that  s is small. You may look for the main term of this expression. If yes, then let us make the following:
expr3 = First[Series[expr2, {s, 0, 1}] // Normal]

(*   (b (-8 + P) Sqrt[s] z Sin[x])/(16 B)   *)

Have fun!
